# socket.io error when forcing websocket communication

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, socket.io

We are having some trouble forcing websocket communication in our application. Basically when we allow polling everything works fine but we saw from time to time errors on websocket communications. After some research we changed the configuration to 
'transports': ['websocket'], upgrade: false

When we restart the sockets are not working anymore and we are getting errors like this one

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://our-server/socket.io/?partnerId=22222&EIO=3&transport=websocket' failed: Compressed bit must be 0 if no negotiated deflate-frame extension
```

We also created an issue that you can find here:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/2925

The server is based on Node.js and the client is an ionic application with AngularJS.

Anyone experience the same issue? Any ideas how to tackle this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was doing wrong the initialization of the websocket client

I was doing:

```
var socketIo = require('socket.io')(server, {
  path: '/myserver/socket.io',
  transports: ['websocket']
});
var client = socketIo.listen(server, {
  path: '/myserver/socket.io',
  transports: ['websocket']
});
```

and this works like a charm:

```
var client = require('socket.io')(server, {
  path: '/myserver/socket.io',
  transports: ['websocket']
});
```